# wxmaxima: plotting a discrete data - can I call the data from an exterior file?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I have a data ([x1,y1],....,[xn,yn])
where $n$ is large, around 700.

I want to plot these data in wxmaxima.

The question is:
 can I store these data in an exterior .txt or .wxmx file and call it from within the code.
How achieve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If the data are coming from some external source, the function `read_nested_list` can read the data as a list of lists of 2 elements [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]. There are other functions for reading from a file -- `?? read` will find the documentation for them.

If the data are generated in Maxima, you can save them to a plain text file via `write_data` and then read them with `read_nested_list` or another read function. Another option is to save them via `save("myfile.lisp", mydata)` which saves `mydata` as Lisp expressions. Then you can say `load("myfile.lisp")` to restore `mydata` in another session.